# Ошибка "append() takes no keyword arguments" при парсинге данных с WEB страницы

Tags: python, python-3.x, парсер, pandas, dataframe

Написал парсер, но почему то выходит ошибка со словарем.

```
from lxml.html import fromstring
import requests
from urllib.parse import urljoin
from pandas import DataFrame, ExcelWriter

url = 'http://reestr.nopriz.ru'

def prinz():
    r = requests.get(url).text
    f = fromstring(r)

    df = DataFrame(columns=('Номер в гос. реестре', 'ИНН', 'ОГРН', 'Федеральный округ', 'Адрес местонахождения', 'Фактический адрес', 'Телефон'
    'Email', 'Адрес сайта', 'Руководитель коллегиального органа СРО', 'Руководитель исполнительного органа СРО', ))

    for value in range(1, 2):
        silk = ('http://reestr.nopriz.ru/?page=%s' % value)

        pr = requests.get(silk).text
        pf = fromstring(pr)
        for dd in pf.cssselect('.col-xs-12 table tr'):
            da = dd.cssselect('tr')[0]
            dhref = da.get('rel')
            dj = urljoin(url, dhref)
            #print(dj)


            dr = requests.get(dj).text
            df = fromstring(dr)

            try:
                nomer = df.cssselect('.col-xs-5 tr td')[1].text_content()
                inn  = df.cssselect('.col-xs-5 tr td')[3].text_content()
                ogrn = df.cssselect('.col-xs-5 tr td')[5].text_content()
                federal = df.cssselect('.col-xs-5 tr td')[7].text_content()
                adress = df.cssselect('.col-xs-5 tr td')[9].text_content()
                factadress = df.cssselect('.col-xs-5 tr td')[11].text_content()
                tel = df.cssselect('.col-xs-5 tr td')[13].text_content()
                email = df.cssselect('.b-table-sro tr td')[15].text_content()
                rykk = df.cssselect('.b-table-sro tr td')[17].text_content()
                rykkisp = df.cssselect('.b-table-sro tr td')[19].text_content()
                obnov = df.cssselect('.b-table-sro tr td')[21].text_content()

            except Exception as e:
                continue

            prizreestr = [('Номер в гос. реестре', nomer), ('ИНН', inn), ('ОГРН', ogrn), ('Федеральный округ', federal), ('Адрес местонахождения', adress), ('Фактический адрес', factadress),
                            ('Телефон', tel), ('Email', email), ('Руководитель коллегиального органа СРО', rykk), ('Руководитель исполнительного органа СРО', rykkisp), ('Обновлено', obnov)]

            df = df.append(dict(prizreestr), ignore_index=True)
            print(df)

    writer = ExcelWriter('prizr.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')
    df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='1', header=True, index=False)
    writer.save()
```

Вывод ошибки:

```
Возникло исключение: TypeError
append() takes no keyword arguments
  File "C:\Users\artdd\github\pythonproject\nopriz.py", line 49, in prinz
    df = df.append(dict(prizreestr), ignore_index=True)
  File "C:\Users\artdd\github\pythonproject\nopriz.py", line 59, in main
    prinz()
  File "C:\Users\artdd\github\pythonproject\nopriz.py", line 62, in <module>
    main()
```

В чем причина ошибки?

Comment: А пробовали просто передать список? `prizreestr = [nomer, inn, ...]` и `df = df.append(prizreestr, ignore_index=True)`

Comment: Такая же ошибка выходит

Comment: почему ты изобретаешь велоспед ?  Использую регулярные выражения .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Смотрим внимательно:

```
df = DataFrame(columns=('Номер в гос. реестре', 'ИНН', 'ОГРН', 'Федеральный округ', 'Адрес местонахождения', 'Фактический адрес', 'Телефон' ...

...

df = fromstring(dr)

...

df = df.append(dict(prizreestr), ignore_index=True)
```

---

Переменная `df` в определенный момент времени перестает хранить ссылку на объект типа `DataFrame`.

Вместо `df = fromstring(dr)` назовите например `root = fromstring(dr)`, ну и, соответственно, `root.cssselect`

А объект, что вернулся из `fromstring` тоже имел метод `append`, но не поддерживал keyword-аргументы, а у вас это был `ignore_index`

Comment: спасибо, черт как я не заметил

Answer (score 5):

Воспользуйтесь магиями `lxml` и `Pandas`:

```
import pandas as pd
import requests
from lxml.html import fromstring
from urllib.parse import urljoin

url = 'http://reestr.nopriz.ru'

def parse_page(url=url):
    r = requests.get(url)
    if not r.ok:
        r.raise_for_status()
    tree = fromstring(r.text)
    urls = [urljoin(url, x.attrib['rel'])
            for x in tree.cssselect('.col-xs-12 table tbody tr')]
    dfs = []
    for u in urls:
        dfs.append(pd.concat([d.set_index(0).T for d in pd.read_html(u)], axis=1))
    return pd.concat(dfs, ignore_index=True)


df = parse_page(url)
```

Результат:

```
In [118]: df
Out[118]:
0  Номер в гос. реестре:               ...                                      Обновлено:
0     СРО-И-001-28042009               ...                 28.11.2018 в 12:36 (UTC +03:00)
1     СРО-И-002-03082009               ...                 15.11.2018 в 15:48 (UTC +03:00)
2     СРО-И-003-14092009               ...                 04.12.2018 в 17:21 (UTC +03:00)
3     СРО-И-004-29092009               ...                 27.11.2018 в 09:57 (UTC +03:00)
4     СРО-И-005-26102009               ...                 28.12.2017 в 14:39 (UTC +03:00)
5     СРО-И-006-09112009               ...                 29.11.2018 в 16:20 (UTC +03:00)
6     СРО-И-007-30112009               ...                 28.11.2018 в 13:06 (UTC +03:00)
7     СРО-И-008-30112009               ...                 20.11.2018 в 14:32 (UTC +03:00)
8     СРО-И-009-07122009               ...                 03.08.2018 в 11:02 (UTC +03:00)
9     СРО-И-010-11122009               ...                 19.11.2018 в 12:40 (UTC +03:00)
10    СРО-И-011-23122009               ...                 19.11.2018 в 14:08 (UTC +03:00)
11    СРО-И-012-24122009               ...                 03.12.2018 в 18:47 (UTC +03:00)
12    СРО-И-013-25122009               ...                 03.12.2018 в 12:27 (UTC +03:00)
13    СРО-И-014-25122009               ...                 28.11.2018 в 10:40 (UTC +03:00)
14    СРО-И-015-25122009               ...                 12.11.2018 в 10:01 (UTC +03:00)
15    СРО-И-016-28122009               ...                 27.11.2018 в 09:38 (UTC +03:00)
16    СРО-И-017-29122009               ...                 03.12.2018 в 10:12 (UTC +03:00)
17    СРО-И-018-30122009               ...                 04.12.2018 в 18:48 (UTC +03:00)
18    СРО-И-019-11012010               ...                 03.12.2018 в 12:12 (UTC +03:00)
19    СРО-И-020-11012010               ...                 28.11.2018 в 10:54 (UTC +03:00)

[20 rows x 12 columns]

In [119]: df.columns
Out[119]:
Index(['Номер в гос. реестре:', 'ИНН:', 'ОГРН:', 'Федеральный округ:', 'Адрес местонахождения:', 'Фактический адрес:', 'Телефон:',
       'Email:', 'Адрес сайта:', 'Руководитель коллегиального органа СРО:', 'Руководитель исполнительного органа СРО:', 'Обновлено:'],
      dtype='object', name=0)
```

NOTE: приведенная в ответе функция парсит одну страницу. Добавить цикл по страницам не должно составить труда...

Comment: Кст, `r.raise_for_status()` можно вызывать и без проверки `ok`: https://github.com/requests/requests/blob/bedd9284c9646e50c10b3defdf519d4ba479e2c7/requests/models.py#L917 потому что сам `ok` вызывает `raise_for_status`: https://github.com/requests/requests/blob/bedd9284c9646e50c10b3defdf519d4ba479e2c7/requests/models.py#L693 :)

Comment: @gil9red, спасибо за ссылки. Мне надо будет привыкнуть к такому стилю... Сейчас в глаза бросается если `r.raise_for_status()` вызывается без проверки.

Comment: Ну да ) зато, смысла кидать ислючение на 1xx, 2xx и 3xx особо нет (хотя вот на 3xx в принципе можно было), но мы ведь говорим об ошибках, а это все 4xx и 5xx :)

Answer (score 1):

Возможно у вас ошибка в блоке try-except

Во всяком случае содержимое страницы и словаря сильно отличается.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]